# Opengl framebuffer rendering looks wierd

Tags: java, opengl, framebuffer, tile

**The Original Problem:**

I'm making a 2d game in OpenGL that uses tiles to draw a map. At the moment, each tile is drawn individually on a quad. The code for the tile rendering is:

```
@Override
public void render() {
    if (parentTileSet.getTexture() == null)
        return;

    float alpha = parentLayer.getOpacity();
    if (alpha < 0)
        alpha = 0;
    glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, alpha); //Set alpha to parent layer's alpha

    parentTileSet.getTexture().bind(); //Bind texture

    float bx = parentTileSet.getTileWidth() / 2; //Half the width
    float by = parentTileSet.getTileHeight() / 2; //Half the height
    float x = getX(), y = getY();
    float z = 0f;

    glPushMatrix(); //Save the current view matrix
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0f); //Translate to the tile's position

    glRotatef(rotate, 0f, 0f, 1f); //Rotate the tile if it has a rotation
    if ((flipType & 1) > 0) //Are we flipping horizontally?
        glScalef(-1f, 1f, 1f);
    if ((flipType & 2) > 0) //Are we flipping vertically?
        glScalef(1f, -1f, 1f);

    //Draw the tile
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(tex_cords.bottom_left.x, tex_cords.bottom_left.y); //bottom left
    glVertex3f(-bx, -by, z);
    glTexCoord2f(tex_cords.bottom_right.x, tex_cords.bottom_right.y); //bottom right
    glVertex3f(bx, -by, z);
    glTexCoord2f(tex_cords.top_right.x, tex_cords.top_right.y); //top right
    glVertex3f(bx, by, z);
    glTexCoord2f(tex_cords.top_left.x, tex_cords.top_left.y); //top left
    glVertex3f(-bx, by, z);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix(); //Reload the view matrix to original state
    parentTileSet.getTexture().unbind(); //Unbind the texture

}
```

And the result looks like the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/maIXk.jpg

Which is good. However, the FPS could be better, and this especially becomes an issue when the maps become more detailed. (The FPS drops to about 20).

**My Ideal Solution:**

Since the tiles will never change position or animate, if I render all the tiles to a texture once, and just draw that texture, then performance will increase!

So, I made a framebuffer using the following class:

```
public class Framebuffer implements Drawable {
private int fID, tID;

protected int width, height;

public Framebuffer(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public void generate() {
    fID = glGenFramebuffers();
    tID = glGenTextures();

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tID);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_INT, (ByteBuffer) null);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tID, 0);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        throw new RuntimeException("Framebuffer configuration error.");
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}

public void begin() {
    glPushMatrix();
    glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fID);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

public void end() {
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPopAttrib();
}

@Override
public void render() {
    float x = 0f;
    float y = 0f;
    float z = 0f;
    float bx = (this.width)/2f;
    float by = (this.height)/2f;

    glPushMatrix();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tID);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f); //bottom left
    glVertex3f(x - bx, y - by, z);
    glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f); //bottom right
    glVertex3f(x + bx, y - by, z);
    glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f); //top right
    glVertex3f(x + bx, y + by, z);
    glTexCoord2f(0f, 1f); //top left
    glVertex3f(x - bx, y + by, z);
    glEnd();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

And then use the following code to generate the framebuffer, and render the tiles to the texture:

```
System.out.println("Attempting to generate frame buffer..");

                    try {
                        Framebuffer frame = new Framebuffer(tiledData.getPixelWidth(), tiledData.getPixelHeight());
                        frame.generate();
                        frame.begin();
                        glScalef(0.5f, 0.5f, 1f); //The game is scaled up by 2, so I'm just unscalling here.
                        Iterator<Drawable> drawableIterator = getSortedDrawables();
                        while (drawableIterator.hasNext()) {
                            Drawable d = drawableIterator.next();
                            if (d instanceof TileObject) {
                                TileObject t = (TileObject)d;
                                if (t.isGroundLayer() && !t.isParallaxLayer() && !t.isAnimated()) {
                                    t.render(); //This render method is the one from above
                                    drawableIterator.remove();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        frame.end();
                        System.out.println("Success!");
                        addDrawable(frame);
                    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                        System.out.println("Framebuffers are not supported!");
                    }
```

However, the output is this:

http://puu.sh/8Eemy.jpg

Which is not what I expected to happen. I tried scaling it, moving it, and all sorts of things but I can never get it exactly right.

**My Question**

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to go about this? Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the comments, I've got it to render correctly!

I changed the framebuffer class to be the following:

```
private int fID, tID;

protected int width, height;

public Framebuffer(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public void generate() {
    fID = glGenFramebuffers();
    tID = glGenTextures();

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tID);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_INT, (ByteBuffer) null);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tID, 0);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        throw new RuntimeException("Framebuffer configuration error.");
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}

public void begin() {
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fID);

    glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
}

public void end() {
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPopAttrib();
}

@Override
public void render() {
    float x = this.width / 2f;
    float y = this.height / 2f;
    float z = 0f;
    float bx = (this.width)/2f;
    float by = (this.height)/2f;

    glPushMatrix();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tID);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f); //bottom left
    glVertex3f(x - bx, y - by, z);
    glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f); //bottom right
    glVertex3f(x + bx, y - by, z);
    glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f); //top right
    glVertex3f(x + bx, y + by, z);
    glTexCoord2f(0f, 1f); //top left
    glVertex3f(x - bx, y + by, z);
    glEnd();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

The points of interest here is the begin() and end() method, where I setup a new projection matrix and save the old one, then restore it in the end() method.

Comment: I suspect your problem is to do with your matrices. `glViewport (...)` does not change the clipping characteristics (e.g. min/max x,y,z coordinates) of your projection, only the region of the framebuffer (in window-space coordinates) that geometry projects to. If you use whatever projection matrix happened to be lying around when you draw into your tiles, rather than setting up an appropriate one, you may be encountering a number of weird things like this.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So how would I go about fixing that..? Would I call glLoadIdentity() or is something else I need to do..? Like I said in the OP, I'm very new to framebuffers so I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: No, an identity matrix definitely is not going to help you here, unless your tiles all have widths/heights <= **2.0**. You need to setup a projection matrix to match the dimensions of your tile, the same way you already did for the viewport. The simplest thing would be something to the effect of `glOrtho (0, width, 0, height, -1, 1);` (with matrix mode set to Projection, of course).

Comment: You may need `glOrtho (-width/2.0, width/2.0, -height/2.0, height/2.0, -1, 1)` since your tile's origin appears to be (-width/2,-height/2).

Comment: YES! Thank you! I've updated my OP to show my answer, as StackOverflow wouldn't let me answer my own question.